# How do I refresh other div by jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have call two different pages in one page via iframe.One for adding record and other for displaying all record. Here I want when I add any record from first iframe, reload second iframe.

```
<div style="float:left">
    <iframe src="dial_card.php" width="300" height="400" scrolling='no' seamless="no" frameborder="0"></iframe> </div>
<div style="float:left; margin-left:40px" id="dial_list1">
    <iframe src="dial_list.php" width="500" height="400" scrolling='no' frameborder="1" id="dial_list"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: some code example, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: There is already similar question answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249809/reload-an-iframe-with-jquery