# ckFinder - simulate refresh click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ckfinder

Am trying to have jQuery simulate a click of ckFinder's refresh button on loading a tab. Regardless of what code I use, the click does not register/alert. Using Firebug, I grabbed the refresh button source:

```
    <a onclick="window.parent.CKFinder._.callFunction(3, this); return false;" 
    onfocus="window.parent.CKFinder._.uiButtonFocus(1, event);" 
    onkeydown="window.parent.CKFinder._.uiButtonKeydown(1, event);" 
    onblur="this.style.cssText = this.style.cssText;" aria-labelledby="cke_10_label" 
    role="button" hidefocus="true" tabindex="-1" title="Refresh" 
    href="javascript:void('Refresh')" class="cke_button_refresh cke_off" id="cke_10" style="">
    <span class="cke_icon"></span>
    <span class="cke_label" id="cke_10_label">Refresh</span></a>
```

I've tried the following code samples, even going to root/generic tags, which don't work.

```
   $('span').click(function(){
     var t = $(this).text();
     alert(t);
   });

  $("#cke_10").click(function() { alert('cke_10'); });
  $("a").click(function() { alert('a click'); });
  $("a#cke_10").click(function() { alert('a cke click'); });
  $("#cke_10_label").click(function() { alert('cke label'); });
  $("span#cke_10_label").click(function() { alert('span cke label'); });
```

Anyone have any luck with getting the Refresh button to alert when clicked?

Comment: Was the jQuery file included in the first place??

Comment: Yes, it's a main jQuery file that is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, I had two IDs both set as "id" which was confusing the refresh. Then using this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4249906/850904 I managed to refresh the iFrame as needed.