# How can I reload an iframe on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reload an iframe with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249809/reload-an-iframe-with-jquery)

How can I cause an `<iframe>` to reload on a click event?

I tried this, but it is not working:

```
jQuery("#link").click(function(){
   jQuery('#iframeID')[0].reload();
})
```

Comment: This might already be the answer [iframe Jquery reload][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249809/reload-an-iframe-with-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

like this

```
document.getElementById('iframeID').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

or via

```
document.getElementById('iframeID').src = document.getElementById('iframeID').src;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $("#reload").click(function() {
        jQuery.each($("iframe"), function() {
            $(this).attr({
                src: $(this).attr("src")
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
```

This above code will reload every iframe in your page, every time the link with `id=reload` is clicked

Thanks to @Haim Evgi

Or you can do the same also like this

```
$('iframe').each(function() {
  this.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful to append a 'reload' class to all my modals with videos within and this handles them all perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$("#iframe").attr('src', ($('#iframe').attr('src'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('ID');

iframe.src = iframe.src;
```