# CORS error when trying to reload an embedded iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, reload, same-origin-policy

I am trying to force-reload the contents of an iframe (force-reload meaning the browser cache should not be used). From the soltuion [Reload an iframe with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249809/reload-an-iframe-with-jquery) here, I can do this via this javascript code:

```
document.getElementById(FrameID).contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

But I am hitting the same-origin policy error. But I did enable CORS on both, the page that has the iframe embedded and the page that is loaded within the iframe. From the web development tools I have verified that on *both* loads, the CORS header is present:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Although both sides are under different domains, I control both of them and can send the CORS header or any other header, if required.

Whats the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Although this question is very old, it has a lot of views, so I'm going to link this nice [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4062084/824796) here for developers with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is not needed for the described case. [The same origin policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy) doesn't allow accessing DOM properties and methods across different domains. You can use [postMessage JavaScript API](http://help.dottoro.com/ljgheukc.php) for enabling communication between IFRAME and parent page.

Answer (score 0):

This script was working with images/jpg (same URL) fine:

```
document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

With Firefox 107.0 (64-Bit) and iframe the following console message was displayed when tried to reload application/pdf with embedded firefox pdf viewer:

```
DOMException: Permission denied to access property "reload" on cross-origin object
```

with [Trick evko/joe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4062084/824796) both work pdf and jpg (etc.)

```js
try {
 document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.location.reload();
}catch(e){
 document.getElementById('iframe_id').src = document.getElementById('iframe_id').src;
 console.warn(e);
}
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe_id" src="dynamic_image_or_pdf.php"></iframe>
```

it worked