# jQuery iframe loading in chrome, but not in FF and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, iframe, mapbox

I've had some help writing a little jquery coding to allow toggling between different embedded iframes using their id's in the jquery to switch.

```
<div id="sins">
<iframe width='860' height='560' frameBorder='0' src='http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/eibenm.Lust.html#4/36.13779999999999/-95.88870000000001' id="Image1" ></iframe>      
<iframe width='860' height='560' frameBorder='0' src='http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/eibenm.Gluttony.html#4/36.13779999999999/-95.88870000000001' id="Image2" ></iframe>
</div><!-- sins -->

<div id="links">
<a href="#"><img src="Images/1Lust.png" width="160" height="50" id="button1" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="Images/2Gluttony.png" width="160" height="50" id="button2" /></a> 
</div><!-- links -->

// this block will cause the sins maps to fade
// into each other on button clicks
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Image1').fadeIn(1500);
    var curr_img_id = 'Image1';
    $('#links img').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('id').match(/(\d)$/)) {
            var new_img_id = 'Image' + RegExp.$1;
            $('#' + curr_img_id).fadeOut(1000, 0.0, function() {
                $('#' + new_img_id).fadeIn(1000);                   
            });
            curr_img_id = new_img_id;
        }
    });
});
```

For the full code, see:
http://users.humboldt.edu/eibenm/sheepallenge.html

The problem is that this code works perfectly in chrome and safari, but I'm having issues in IE and FF.  The initial iframe will load in as expected, but when I click on a link to toggle to a different one, it won't load up.  I can deal with it not working on IE, but I'd prefer to have FF compatibility.  Any help is appreciated!

Additionally, I'm not sure if this would affect anything, but the embedded iframe is through mapbox which uses mapbox.js.

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the link, frame is loading perfectly but the issue here is the source for this frame is not getting rendered properly. So you need to manually reload the iframe every time you click on the navigation link. For testing purpose, just right click on the frame and click reload, you will see the image. You have to do the same via code)

Try this :  [Reload an iframe with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249809/reload-an-iframe-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$('#links img').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('id').match(/(\d)$/)) {
        var new_img_id = 'Image' + RegExp.$1;
        $('#' + curr_img_id).fadeOut(1000, 0.0, function() {
            $('#' + new_img_id).fadeIn(1000);

            // hack for your code
             var iframe = document.getElementById(new_img_id);
             iframe.src = iframe.src;   
        });
        curr_img_id = new_img_id;
    }
});
```