# Jquery setting .attr to an iframe scrolling=yes

Tags: jquery, iframe, scrollbar

I have an iframe with "scrolling="no"" and a button that sets iframe attribute to scrolling="yes", when it's needed.

```
    $("#button3").click(function(){
    $( "#iframe_id" ).attr( "scrolling", "yes" );});
```

But the scroll bar doesn't appear, when i press the button3, only after i refresh the iframe.
How to force the srcoll bar appear instantly?

How it works now: 
http://jsfiddle.net/77van/k8GhZ/1/

Comment: Works in Firefox at least

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/77van/k8GhZ/10/ now it works , i reload the iframe with jquery , source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249809/reload-an-iframe-with-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now jquery sets `.attr` to `scrolling="yes"` and reloads the iframe!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button3").click(function () {
        $("#iframe_id").attr("scrolling", "yes");
        $('#iframe_id').attr("src", $('#iframe_id').attr("src"));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/77van/k8GhZ/10/

Comment: You should do it like this so the jQuery call is being "cached"  https://gist.github.com/fedmich/8947380

Answer (score 2):

Trust me, there is no way you can do it with iframe. It will not work in Chrome or IE. I have played a lot with iFrame in past and such things never worked for me.

iFrame simply doesn't accept any changes, after it's loaded

Comment: yeah, thx, i reload the iframe with the same click on the button3 now