# AngularJS instant / automatic refresh without using WebSockets

Tags: hibernate, angularjs, tomcat, websocket, long-polling

I am building a web application on Java, that has a front-end using Angular JS. Here is the stack:
`Apache Tomcat 7.0.40`
`Hibernate 4.2.3`
`Jersey 1.1.17`
`Jackson 1.9.2`
`Angular JS 1.2.4`
I need to support IE 8 clients as well (no particular constraint on Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox). Therefore, using Websockets for instant refresh is ruled out. I have also evaluated [Brian Ford's utility](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/); but since it uses nodejs, it becomes difficult to integrate with Tomcat Server (at least that is what I understood)
Another option is to use DWR / CometD / Comet (a.k.a long polling) - it posed some issues with Angular JS registry refresh and I did not find suitable answer anywhere for the latter.
Is there a way to implement instant refresh in Angular JS without using WebSockets? Remember - I need to support at least IE 8!
Any help will be highly appreciated.
**EDIT**
Forgot to mention that I am calling RESTful services from front end!

Comment: We recently published a live demo of AngularJS and Lightstreamer (which supports even IE6). Do you need anything like this?
ARTICLE: http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/11/yet-another-integration-angularjs.html - LIVE DEMO: http://demos.lightstreamer.com/AngularJSDemo/

Comment: Can I use Lightstreamer with Apache Tomcat? Do I have to run 2 servers then? I have a whole stack of Hibernate based entities running on the back-end

Comment: Yes, you have to run two servers. Lightstreamer runs as a stand-alone server because it's highly optimized for real-time traffic. Sharing resources with Tomcat or any web server would not allow to optimize TCP management, threading model, and memory. So, Tomcat will deliver all the request/response resources, while Lightstreamer will deliver the streaming messages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [refreshing iframe contents in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718393/refreshing-iframe-contents-in-angularjs)

Comment: I ended up using [Atmosphere JS](http://atmospherejs.com). It is a great utility that can support both web sockets as well as long polling depending on client (browser) capability. It supports IE 8 as well... in the sense it "switches" to long polling when a non-HTML5 browser client is detected. I was easily able to integrate with my Angular JS / Java application.

Cheers