# How to refresh an already opened FancyBox popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Can anyone tell me how to refresh a Fancybox popup ?

Here is how i create it.

```
       $.fancybox({
        'width'  : 470,           // set the width
        'height' : 190, 
        'autoSize': false, 
        'transitionIn': 'fade', 
        'transitionOut': 'fade', 
        'href': 'pop.jsp', 
        'autoDimension' : false,
        'type': 'iframe',
    });
```

Comment: what is the action triggering the refresh?

Comment: Steps : 1. open popup
2. do a server side ajax
3. push values to div in pop
4. refresh the popup

Comment: the server side ajax is done in the parent or in pop.jsp?
(couldn't you just close and reopen the fancybox?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to do it by refering to `$('iframe.fancybox-iframe')`, with something like this:

`$('iframe.fancybox-iframe').attr('src', function(i, val){return val;});`

(according to [Reload an iframe with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249809/reload-an-iframe-with-jquery))

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pataluc/aLbYr/

Comment: Although this refreshes the iframe indeed from the parent page, it's not clear if this has to be triggered from the iframe itself after a successful ajax request. In the last case, the iframed page would only need to call `location.reload(true)`