# Manually trigger onLoad event of iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, triggers

I have two different pages: the main page and the second page (that will be displayed in the main page as an iFrame).

The fact is that I cannot edit the main page, except from the iFrame href link.
What I want to do is to manually trigger the iFrame "onLoad" event in the main page, by using jQuery in the second page.

This is getting really hard cause of the impossibility to edit the main page, and the only thing I managed to do is to manually trigger the "ready" event on the second page, but this is not related to the "onLoad" event, unfortunately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you change source of iframe, load will trigger automatically. Some more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249809/reload-an-iframe-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
parent.$("iframe[src=myhref]").trigger("onload");
```