# How to refresh iframe after regular interval in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I want to auto refresh iframe loading php page but its refreshing whole page instead of refreshing iframe only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Fouad Ali</title>
<script>
var links = "/proj/index.php";
var i = 0;
var renew = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("foo").src = links;        
  // alert("refreshed");
},5000);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<iframe id="foo" src="/proj/index.php"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reload an iframe with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249809/reload-an-iframe-with-jquery)

Comment: _but its refreshing whole page instead of refreshing iframe only._ - are you saying that the code you posted refreshes the whole page?

Comment: i want to refresh iframe only which is loading php page . actualy i want to refresh php page thats why i refreshing iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script>
   var src = $('#foo').attr('src');
   setInterval(function () {
        $('#foo').remove();
        var iframe_html = '<iframe src="'+ src +'" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>';
        $('#iframe').html(iframe_html);
    }, 1000);
</script>
<span id="iframe">
    <iframe id="foo" src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</span>
```

If you are using any server side language the page will always look like refreshing itself but if you check the net calls of the page it will shows you one hit for your page and repetitive hits for iframe's src. Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   setInterval(refreshIframe, 5000);
   function refreshIframe() {
       var frame = document.getElementById("Frame");
       frame.src = frame.src;
   }
</script>

<iframe id="Frame" src="http://www.aspforums.net" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this script will help you:

```
<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 30000);

function reloadIFrame() {
    document.frames["myiframe"].location.reload();
}

</script>
```

and html code for iframe is:

```
<iframe name="myiframe" src="/proj/index.php"></iframe>
```

Comment: can you give working fiddle of it because i dnt know why its not working for me in chrome version 44

Comment: @nagi: I have used this line of code in my phonegap project. It is working fine for me. I don't have any fiddle for this. But if you send me your code, I can check that one