# Refreshing an iframe gives 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, refresh

I create an iframe with content, the page is displayed without an error. When I refresh the iframe (after 3 seconds), I get an 404. I've tried different approaches like adding a metadata refresh tag, plain JS, jquery,... A 'working' example can be found here; https://jsfiddle.net/RaZoR_BlaZe/ezswtxk7/32/

```html
<div class="second-row">
  <iframe name="presentatie" id="presframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/
      13WCxr5uG4Jqw8bPJzB6dIdQ3DP2H4nBFRH8FHxlqK0Q/preview"></iframe>
</div>
```

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('#presframe').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me, the content is reloaded without a 404. However, why would you want to refresh the iframe every 3 seconds in the first place?

Comment: Does `$('#presframe').attr('src', $('#presframe').attr('src'));` fix it for you? In which case this would be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249809/reload-an-iframe-with-jquery).

Comment: You can use this: https://jsfiddle.net/ezswtxk7/34/